# Perform synchronization HTTP request in reactjs using Axios

Tags: reactjs, synchronization, axios

I am trying to request more than one api request in reactjs using axios. The issue is that I want to make all request as a sync. 
  In the 1st request, I performed a post api request and then in the 2nd request I performed a get request. I thought it will execute orderly. But rather, it makes all request as async and executes 2nd request before the execution of a 1st request. So how do I make this as a Sync?
  Even I tried to put the 2nd request inside the 1st request axios .then() but still it is not working.
  Anyone Let me know how to make sync HTTP request using axios or other HTTP libraries in reactjs.

Comment: axios by is Promised based meaning that it will always be async. To make a call using axios "synchronous", you can use [async/await](https://gist.github.com/wesbos/1866f918824936ffb73d8fd0b02879b4).

Answer (score 0):

Performing multiple concurrent requests :

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

see : https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: hi toufek i don't want my request as async. What I need is i want to request all my api call as sync